# Got Error : "_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC10ChartsDemo12XYMarkerView" in Charts,

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, charts, ios-charts

I have used “Charts” library in to my project to display Stacked Bar Chart.
and it is woking fine.
Library : https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Now, I want to add tool tip to my project to display values.

Like :

[image]

I have already followed these steps :

- Drag the Charts.xcodeproj to your project.
- Go to your target's settings, hit the "+" under the "Embedded Binaries" section, and select the Charts.framework
- @import Charts
- When using Swift in an ObjC project:
  •   You need to import your Bridging Header. Usually it is "YourProject-Swift.h", so in ChartsDemo it's "ChartsDemo-Swift.h".
  •   Do not try to actually include "ChartsDemo-Swift.h" in your project :-)
  •   (Xcode 8.2+) Under "Build Options", mark "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries"

And i have added this code which is already mentioned in its demo project.

[image]

But i got this error:

[image]

Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: May I Know Project name as b'cus bridger header is start with your Project name-Swift.h `#import "ProjectName-Swift.h"` ?

Comment: @CodeChanger yah i have added.

Comment: Still problem is there or you have resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this steps:

**Disabled BITE_CODE >  Added all needed frameworks for your framework >
The linker flag -ObjC (not -Objc) > Clean > Run**

Answer (score 0):

You say you have done this step: "When using Swift in an ObjC project" and then you say you have done the step of "adding the Objective-C code from the demo".

Does this mean you are actually using swift in your project, but then trying to add Objective-C code to it? 
There is no swift code in the demos, so you have to convert the demo code to swift before using it.